# identify if categorical column change value considering direction of change in SQL oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data with 4 columns: company_id, obs_period (observation period), hist_period (historical observation period) and is_payroll (payroll status of company). I want to create dummy variable (dummy) that identify if company left payroll status (e.g. is_payroll column change from P to NP).
how can I solve this problem in Oracle SQL.

| compay_NO | obs_period | hist_period | is_payroll | dummy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2018/10 | NP | 0 |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2018/11 | NP | 0 |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2018/12 | NP | 0 |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2019/01 | P | 0 |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2019/02 | P | 0 |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2019/03 | P | 0 |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2019/04 | P | 0 |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2019/05 | P | 0 |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2019/06 | P | 0 |
| 11 | 2020/09 | 2019/07 | P | 0 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2019/08 | P | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2019/09 | P | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2019/10 | P | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2019/11 | P | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2019/12 | P | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2020/01 | NP | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2020/02 | NP | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2020/03 | NP | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2020/04 | NP | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2020/05 | NP | 1 |
| 12 | 2020/09 | 2020/06 | NP | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option: compare `is_payroll` with the next `is_payroll` per each `company_no` (sorted by `hist_period`); if there was switch from `P` to `NP`, then `dummy = 1`:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select company_no,
  3            hist_period,
  4            is_payroll,
  5            --
  6            case when is_payroll = 'P' and
  7                      lead(is_payroll) over (partition by company_no
  8                                             order by hist_period) = 'NP' then 1
  9                 else 0
 10            end dummy
 11     from test t
 12    )
 13  select company_no,
 14         hist_period,
 15         is_payroll,
 16         max(dummy) over (partition by company_no) dummy
 17  from temp;

COMPANY_NO HIST_PERIOD  IS_PAYROLL      DUMMY
---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
        11 2018/10      NP                  0
        11 2018/11      NP                  0
        11 2018/12      NP                  0
        11 2019/01      P                   0
        11 2019/02      P                   0
        11 2019/03      P                   0
        12 2019/11      P                   1
        12 2019/12      P                   1
        12 2020/01      NP                  1
        12 2020/02      NP                  1
        12 2020/03      NP                  1

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```